# Align TextField and FlatButton in a Row

Tags: dart, flutter

I've the below code working fine, and showing the FlatButton under the TextField:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LocationCapture extends StatelessWidget {
  LocationCapture(this.clickCallback, this.tc);
  final TextEditingController tc;
  final VoidCallback clickCallback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
      //    Row(
      //        children: <Widget>[
                TextField(controller: tc,),
                FlatButton(
                  child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
                  onPressed: () => clickCallback(),
                )
      //    ])
    ]);
  }
}
```

I tried adding `Row` to make them in single line, but it is not working, and showing blank screen!!

** UPDATE**

I was able to put them in line, by wrapping each element into a container, but still not happy for this as it require me to assign the container width, I need this to be done automatically:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          width: 180,
          child: TextField(
              controller: tc,
              enabled: false,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "")
          )
      ),
      Container(
          child: FlatButton(
                 child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
                 onPressed: () => clickCallback(),
          )
      ),
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

**textDirection** property of **Row()** widget will allow you to start the positioning of the children widget from the mentioned directions.

NOTE :- **You can remove or comment out the 'textDirection' if your are using MaterialApp() widget in your project. It takes care of the textDirection.

**Expanded()** widget is used to occupy the remaining whole space.

```
 child: Row(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Demo Button")),
              Expanded(child: TextFormField())
            ],
          )
```